# How to output the taxonomy term name in a widget

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I have a taxonomy for example "country" and I want to simply display the term in the side bar eg. New Zealand.
There is only one possible taxonomy per post so I don't need to create a list or anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check the properties of [`get_queried_object()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object/).

Sample code:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: Current Term Widget
 */

add_action( 'widgets_init', array ( 'Current_Term_Widget', 'register' ) );

class Current_Term_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct( 'current_term', 'Current Term' );
    }
    public function widget( $args, $instance )
    {
        if ( isset ( get_queried_object()->taxonomy )
            && isset( get_queried_object()->name )
        )
        {
            return print $args['before_widget']
                . '<b style="padding:10px;border:3px solid red">'
                . get_queried_object()->name
                . '</b>'
                . $args['after_widget'];
        }
    }
    public static function register()
    {
        register_widget( __CLASS__ );
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot for the archive of category **Cat B** from the [test data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test):

[image]

To restrict the widget output to a taxonomy compare `get_queried_object()->taxonomy` with your registered taxonomy name.