# Add custom taxonomy to title tag

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I'm using Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin for a variety of websites. In setting title tag templates with his `%%category%%` syntax, I've figured out that you can reference custom fields by using `%%cf_<custom_field_name>%%`.

What I haven't been able to figure out is how to reference custom taxonomies. Within a custom post type, I have a category that I want to reference (i.e. `customcategory`). If I try adding `%%customcategory%%`, it doesn't work. Does anyone know if this is possible with the WordPress SEO plugin or point me in the right direction if I need to add a function to work with the plugin?

Comment: Any luck on trying to figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a filter for the title element’s content – hook `'wp_title'` – and add any data you want to it. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52157/73) for an example.

On archives use [`get_queried_object()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object/) to [detected the taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53554/73), on singular views (posts, pages, custom post types) the global `$post` is available.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try %%ct_%% ? For me its working when added to post titles.

Comment: This seems like more of a request for more information than an answer. At least provide more detail if you can.