# Change <title> of each paginated page

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Page number to Meta Description in Wordpress SEO by Yoast](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52002/add-page-number-to-meta-description-in-wordpress-seo-by-yoast)

I just had an SEO specialist do an audit on our site and one of the suggestions was to change each paginated page `<title>` tag because we could be penalized for duplicate content.

I use SEO Ultimate and while there is a title rewriter, there doesn't appear to be a way to change titles based on pagination for individual pages.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about a link to the plugin, so we can take a look at the code?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-ultimate/?

Comment: Will your problem be solved by [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52002/add-page-number-to-meta-description-in-wordpress-seo-by-yoast/52157#52157)?

Comment: The same page title, yet on different URLs, is not grounds for penalization. Duplicating content excessively especially within the context of your body content through out your site may be cause for concern. The `<title>` attribute on the other hand should be different per page, based on context to give you the most value out of your SEO efforts in terms of the keyword phrases you wish to rank for, however by not changing it page by page, the only thing you are doing is not giving yourself the best possible relationship between your page content and title and thus your ranking my reflect that.